# Input and Output Audio not Working. Speakers do not work and neither does microphone. Wanting to switch to Ubuntu, everything works with Windows 11

Tags: dual-boot, sound, asus, microphone

I recently switched to Ubuntu (Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Release: 22.04), but my input and output sound do not work. Nothing is muted and I have checked everything in settings.Everything works great though if I go back into Windows 11. Audio however does work if I use my headphones, but does not work without them.

I own a Asus Zenbook 14 oled. Model UM3402Y. Here is in depth info on my laptop...

```
- Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  16
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-15
Vendor ID:               AuthenticAMD
  Model name:            AMD Ryzen 7 5825U with Radeon Graphics
    CPU family:          25
    Model:               80
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  8
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            0
    Frequency boost:     enabled
    CPU max MHz:         4546.8750
    CPU min MHz:         1600.0000
    BogoMIPS:            3992.21
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1
                         gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf rapl pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse
                         4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs ski
                         nit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp vmmcall fsg
                         sbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cqm rdt_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_oc
                         cup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local clzero irperf xsaveerptr rdpru wbnoinvd cppc arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clea
                         n flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif v_spec_ctrl umip pku ospke vaes vpclmulqdq rdpid overfl
                         ow_recov succor smca fsrm
Virtualization features: 
  Virtualization:        AMD-V
Caches (sum of all):     
  L1d:                   256 KiB (8 instances)
  L1i:                   256 KiB (8 instances)
  L2:                    4 MiB (8 instances)
  L3:                    16 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:                    
  NUMA node(s):          1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-15
Vulnerabilities:         
  Gather data sampling:  Not affected
  Itlb multihit:         Not affected
  L1tf:                  Not affected
  Mds:                   Not affected
  Meltdown:              Not affected
  Mmio stale data:       Not affected
  Retbleed:              Not affected
  Spec rstack overflow:  Mitigation; safe RET, no microcode
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Retpolines, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP always-on, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS Not affected
  Srbds:                 Not affected
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected
```

My current audio device (and only option for output) is "Speaker- Family 17h(models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller." For input it is "Digital Microphone-Family 17h(Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller." Neither work when I try to test audio through settings or if I try to test audio by playing music or a video.

I have tried many things to fix this issue but nothing has worked so far. Please let me know if there is any other needed information.

I updated my bios. My model is UM3402ya so it is up to date at version 305.

To add as well, the touchscreen feature also does not work in Ubuntu (But still does in windows)

Update: Audio input works now after kernel updates, but still no external output.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your system firmware is current. If it isn't, update it.

It looks to me like the Zenbook 14 OLED is a model UX3402, but you should check that.

If it is, the current BIOS is version 310:

https://www.asus.com/laptops/for-home/zenbook/zenbook-14-oled-ux3402/helpdesk_bios?model2Name=zenbook-14-oled-ux3402

Comment: Yes my model is um3402ya (forgot to say that). It is up to date with the BIOS version 305, which I believe to be the max version.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry that didn't help, then. It might be worth trying Ubuntu 23.10, just booted from USB hey would be enough, and seeing if that's able you drive the sound chip correctly. (Ventoy is very handy for testing other distros and things.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same computer and encountered the same issue. I finally managed to solve it with this driver I found on GitHub. Hope it helps!

[UM3402 Audio Driver](https://github.com/farfaaa/asus_zenbook_UM3402YA)